# Full height div in Bootstrap 4 columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I would like to have all my `.element` at the same height and the image vertical align middle if it's too small to be full size.
I tried so many things but I can't find the solution

```css
.element {
  border: 10px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.element .inner {
  padding: 15px;
}
.element .inner p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.element a {
  background-color: #424753;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.comohacercrepes.com//ImagenesComoHacerCrepes/ImagenesCrepes/receta-crepes-masa-thermomix.jpg" />
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.gimmesomeoven.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/How-To-Make-Crepes-5.jpg" />
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.comohacercrepes.com//ImagenesComoHacerCrepes/ImagenesCrepes/receta-crepes-masa-thermomix.jpg" />
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.comohacercrepes.com//ImagenesComoHacerCrepes/ImagenesCrepes/receta-crepes-masa-thermomix.jpg" />
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use flex box or jquery.

Comment: I agree that this question could have been asked more thoroughly but with this many views and responses it is a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column` and `flex: 1` on `element`, `inner` and `col-3`. To make `img` centered you can use `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` auto.

```css
.col-3,
.element,
.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
.element {
  border: 10px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.element .inner {
  padding: 15px;
}
.element .inner p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.element a {
  background-color: #424753;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.element img {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.comohacercrepes.com//ImagenesComoHacerCrepes/ImagenesCrepes/receta-crepes-masa-thermomix.jpg" />
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.gimmesomeoven.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/How-To-Make-Crepes-5.jpg" />
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.comohacercrepes.com//ImagenesComoHacerCrepes/ImagenesCrepes/receta-crepes-masa-thermomix.jpg" />
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.comohacercrepes.com//ImagenesComoHacerCrepes/ImagenesCrepes/receta-crepes-masa-thermomix.jpg" />
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new Bootstrap 4 [flexbox utilities](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox) and reduce all the extra CSS..

http://www.codeply.com/go/LBkyWJzTrT

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="element d-flex h-100 flex-wrap justify-content-between">
                <div class="inner d-flex flex-wrap align-self-center justify-content-center">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.comohacercrepes.com//ImagenesComoHacerCrepes/ImagenesCrepes/receta-crepes-masa-thermomix.jpg">
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </div>
                <a href class="align-self-end w-100">Link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="element d-flex h-100 flex-wrap justify-content-between">
                <div class="inner d-flex flex-wrap align-self-center justify-content-center">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.gimmesomeoven.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/How-To-Make-Crepes-5.jpg">
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </div>
                <a href class="align-self-end w-100">Link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="element d-flex h-100 flex-wrap justify-content-between">
                <div class="inner d-flex flex-wrap align-self-center justify-content-center">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.comohacercrepes.com//ImagenesComoHacerCrepes/ImagenesCrepes/receta-crepes-masa-thermomix.jpg">
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </div>
                <a href class="align-self-end w-100">Link</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-3 align-items-center">
            <div class="element d-flex h-100 flex-wrap justify-content-between">
                <div class="inner d-flex flex-wrap align-self-center justify-content-center">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.comohacercrepes.com//ImagenesComoHacerCrepes/ImagenesCrepes/receta-crepes-masa-thermomix.jpg">
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </div>
                <a href class="align-self-end w-100">Link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/LBkyWJzTrT

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this, just added position styling. But with this you also have to write media-query styling.

```css
.element {
  border: 10px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 225px;
  position: relative;
}
.element .inner {
  padding: 15px;
}
.element .inner p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.element a {
  background-color: #424753;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.comohacercrepes.com//ImagenesComoHacerCrepes/ImagenesCrepes/receta-crepes-masa-thermomix.jpg" />
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.gimmesomeoven.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/How-To-Make-Crepes-5.jpg" />
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.comohacercrepes.com//ImagenesComoHacerCrepes/ImagenesCrepes/receta-crepes-masa-thermomix.jpg" />
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.comohacercrepes.com//ImagenesComoHacerCrepes/ImagenesCrepes/receta-crepes-masa-thermomix.jpg" />
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <a>Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```